# ggplot2 histogram facet - include only relevant entries per facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

What I want to accomplish is really simple conceptually, but I don't find a way to do it, unless I do 2 different plots and put them together with grid.arrange, which is not my preferred solution.
I have data from entries of length 9 and length 10 to be faceted in the plot, but I only want the entries of length 9 on the left and the entries of length 10 on the right, not all everywhere with empty histogram bars.

**MWE**

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
my.df <- data.frame(oligo=rep(c("NSSCMGSMNR","SSCMGSMNR","SSCMGSMNRR","VVGAGDVGK",
                                "VVGAVGVGK","VVVGAGDVGK","VVVGAVGVGK"), each=4), 
                    a11.a24=rep(c("-/-","+/-","-/+","+/+"), 7), 
                    a11=rep(c("-","+","-","+"), 7), a24=rep(c("-","-","+","+"), 7),
                    freq1=c(0,3,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,1,2,3,2,0,4,2,1,4,2,3,2,0,4,2,1,4), 
                    freq2=c(0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0,4,4,3,4,3,5,6,5,6,4,3,4,3,5,6,5,6), 
                    freq3=c(3,3,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,1,5,5,2,2,6,6,5,5,5,5,2,2,6,6,5,5), 
                    len=rep(c(10,9,10,9,9,10,10), each=4))
my.df <- with(my.df, my.df[order(my.df$len, my.df$freq1, decreasing=T),])
my.df.m <- melt(my.df, measure.vars=c('a11.a24', 'a11', 'a24'))
my.df.m$oligo <- factor(my.df.m$oligo, levels=unique(my.df.m$oligo))
ggplot(my.df.m, aes(x=oligo)) +
  facet_grid(variable~len, scales="free_y") +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(my.df.m, variable=='a11.a24'),
    aes(y=freq1, fill=value), stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(my.df.m, variable=='a11'),
    aes(y=freq2, fill=value), stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(my.df.m, variable=='a24'),
    aes(y=freq3, fill=value), stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  ggtitle("Number of patients with a given oligo") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size=7), 
        legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="right", 
        legend.background=element_blank(), legend.box.just="left",
        plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold", colour="black", vjust=1.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "num. patients") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "oligo")
```

which produces:
[image]

All entries are in both X axes, and the bars corresponding to the ones of length 10 are empty on the left, and the bars corresponding to the ones of length 9 are empty on the right...
Could I have only entries of length 9 on the left and only entries of length 10 on the right? Thanks

The figure produced brings me to another question regarding the order of the entries... why 9 comes before 10 in the facets, but when arranging the entries in each X axis the ones of length 10 come before the ones of length 9?? In case I wanted to keep all entries everywhere, how could I get a correct order everywhere (9 before 10)??

Note that the solution should be universal, this example is only lengths 9 and 10, but I could have any combination of lengths 8, 9, 10 and 11...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the scales to free on both axes:

`facet_grid(variable~len, scales="free")` (instead of `"free_y"`)

For your second question, the entries are coerced to a factor vector, and the order happens to have entries with length 10 come before length 9. You can reorder them by reordering the levels in the `oligo` factor.

If you want to do it based on the `len` column:

```
my.df.m$oligo = factor(my.df.m$oligo, 
                       levels(my.df.m$oligo)[unique(my.df.m$oligo[order(my.df.m$len)])])
```